# How to disable clicking of ng-repeat rows?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My title says it all. How can I disable the clicking of the ng-repeat rows? Or is it even possible.

Here is a sample code I created:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" class="grid">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="cell">Id</div>
    <div class="cell">Name</div>
  </div>
  <div class="gridBody">
    <div ng-class-even="'even'"
         ng-class-odd="'odd'"
         ng-class="{current: row.current == true}"
         ng-click="clicked(row)"
         ng-repeat="row in topics" class="row"
         ng-disabled="disabled == true">
      <div class="cell">{{row.id}}</div>
      <div class="cell">{{row.name}}</div>
      <div class="cell">{{row.current}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I also created this jsfiddle to show what I'm struggling with.

Edits:

I have edited my jsfiddle to show  more of what im trying to achieve. Hope its clearer now.

http://jsfiddle.net/2jxea6qw/8/

Comment: just remove ng-click

Comment: I believe the `disabled` attribute only works on form controls, so you'd need to implement the "disabled" behaviour yourself. You can do it easily enough in your controller's `clicked` handler :)

Comment: What behavior do you want your user to see specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that using a custom directive and a captured event.

The concept is that you subscribe to the `$element` in link phase of your ClickDisablerDirective the following way:

```
$element.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation()
   e.preventDefault()
}, true)
```

Notice the 'true' param as the last to the addEventListener method: that allows the handler to be notified before any other lower level (bubbling wise) handlers.

Here is the directive in length:

```
myApp.directive('disableClick', [function() {
 return {
    restrict:'A',
    link: function(scope, element) {
      element[0].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation()
        e.preventDefault()
      }, true)
    }
 }
}])
```

I updated your fiddle to show how:
http://jsfiddle.net/2jxea6qw/6/